# Delete duplicate data from a table matched record for some fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table "**Product**" with 7 fields

```
1 Prod_id (PK)
2 Company_id
3 Name
3 Code
5 Start Date
6 End Date
7 Entry Date
8 Description
```

I want to delete all duplicate records (matched 2 t0 6 fields for duplication) and keep only one that has latest Entry Date.

Is there any query in mysql to perform this task.
or
How can i do this using php.

Comment: have you already tried?

Comment: There is a way to do that, but what you did?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unique index and drop the duplicates with

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE Product
ADD UNIQUE INDEX dup_idx (Prod_id, Company_id, Name, Code,Start Date,End Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I had the same problem in the past & found this solution. I mention query as below:

```
DELETE FROM Product 
            USING Product, Product AS P 
            WHERE MIN(DATEDIFF(P.Entry_Date - Product.Entry_Date))
            AND Product.Company_id = P.Company_id 
            AND Product.Name = P.Name 
            AND Product.Code = P.Code;
```

Note: Add & remove fields as per your requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. Its working fine. but it keep last records from duplicate. How i can get records that has entry date close to current date?

Comment: Try this query. I have modified it. Last time mistakenly modified.

Comment: Try this again modified.

Comment: nops! It giving error: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'